# java create tree from array

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception

I need to create an array of trees and take a letter typed by a user and place it into a node. I am getting a NullPointerException error with forest[i].root. How can I fix this?

```
class TreeApp  
{  
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException  
 {  
    Tree forest[] = new Tree[10];  

    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);  

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)  
    {  
        System.out.println("Insert a letter: "); 

        Node newNode = new Node();  
        newNode.iData = kb.next().charAt(0);  

        System.out.println("node: " + newNode.iData );  

        forest[i].root = newNode;
        }  
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Tree forest[] = new Tree[10];
```

The above statement creates an array of type `Tree`, but it does not store any `Tree` instances into the array. So, your array elements are initialized with default `null` value.

You need to initialize your array elements first before accessing them.

Add this line in your for loop: -

```
forest[i] = new Tree();
```

before accessing `forest[i].root`.

Comment: Can you elaborate on index?

Comment: @stevenpepe.. I forgot to add `i` in `forest[] = new Tree()` previously. Of course you need to add that to access array element at that index.